# Upgrade to Lubuntu 17.04 from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

Is it possible to upgrade from Ubuntu to Lubuntu without losing everything? (Files, Accounts, Data, Document, etc.)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to reinstall? Or how to achieved the desired change using only the package manager? A backup is wise in either case, so the 'without losing everything' seems moot.

Comment: I doubt that it's possible. The upgrade process will examine your existing system files and upgrade you to the same flavor and not to another. Also, you may have to go from 16.04 > 16.10 > 17.04 and not straight from 16.04 to 17.04. If you really want Lubuntu 17.04, back up your data and do a clean install including over-writing your existing home folder.

Answer (score 1):

backups are worthwhile - so always backup first.

yep; but still better to backup should anything go wrong.

another alternative is to add LXDE to your existing ubuntu system; eg. my "ubuntu 16.04" system also has `lubuntu-desktop`package installed; so I can at login have unity (standard ubuntu), xfce (xubuntu), lxde (lubuntu), mate (ubuntu-mate).

note: loading many desktops is not intended. loading many desktops like I do can cause them to misbehave, or your system have more quirks than a pure system, but it's an option.  they will all be 16.04; so if its the later 17.04 you want; you'll need to re-install (remembering backups first are a good safety measure!!)